# Oracle function and trigger problems

Tags: sql, oracle, function, triggers

I've been stuck on this thing for a couple days now.  Please help.

I have a database table that defines hunting seasons:

```
create table season(
    season          varchar2(6) not null,
    start_date      date not null,
    end_date        date not null,
    constraint pk_season primary key (season)
);
```

There is an external program that allows end users to update values in this database.  However, this external program does not do any checking on date format when updating the 'start_date' or 'end_date' columns.  To remedy this, I am attempting to create a trigger that takes the input, and applies Oracle's `TO_DATE` function.

Prior to the trigger, I am creating two functions to validate two things: 1) that the date entered is in `MM/DD/YYYY` format and 2) to ensure that the `end_date` is after the `start_date`.

I cannot get any of these to function correctly.  I probably have syntax errors here somewhere, as I am really new at working with triggers and functions in Oracle.  Here's what I have:

```
create or replace function isValidDate(input_date in varchar2) return boolean
is
v_date date;
v_diff number;
begin
    select to_date(input_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') into v_date from dual;
        return true;
    exception when others then
        return false;
end;
end isValidDate;
/
create or replace function isValidDateRange(in_start in varchar2, in_end in varchar2) return     boolean
is
v_diff number;
begin
    select to_date(in_end, 'MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date(in_start, 'MM/DD/YYYY') into v_diff from dual;
        if v_diff >= 0
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        end if;
end;
end isValidDateRange;
/
create trigger date_format
before insert or update on season
for each row
begin
    if isValidDate(:NEW.start_date) then
        if isValidDateRange(:NEW.start_date, :NEW.end_date) then
            :NEW.start_date := TO_DATE(:NEW.start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        else
            raise_application_error(-20100, 'End date must be AFTER Start date');
        end if;
    else
        raise_application_error(-20099, 'Date must be in MM/DD/YYYY format');
    end if;
    if isValidDate(:NEW.end_date) then
        if isValidDateRange(:NEW.start_date, :NEW.end_date) then
            :NEW.end_date := TO_DATE(:NEW.end_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        else
            raise_application_error(-20100, 'End date must be AFTER Start date');
        end if;
    else
        raise_application_error(-20099, 'Date must be in MM/DD/YYYY format');
    end if;
end;
end date_format;
/
```

When I attempt any of these individually, I get `Warning:  Function created with compilation errors.`  When I do `SHOW ERRORS`, it tells me `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"`.  I can't figure out what's going on for the life of me.  Am I doing this all wrong, or am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Open SQL*Plus and compile them. Copy paste the compile time error stack. It will have the error details.

Comment: `start_date` and `end_date` are already defined as `date`, so by the time the trigger "sees" them, they will already be converted to `date`.  There is no good reason to call `isValidDate` at that point, especially since the dates will be converted back to `varchar2` using an implicit date format in the process.  The only remaining function of the trigger is to check that `end_date` is greater than or equal to `start_date`.  Is there a good reason why you're not doing that with a check constraint instead?  If you choose to use a trigger, there's no need for `to_date` or `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `end;` from the two functions and the trigger.  `end <object name>;` serves the same purpose.

Most tools will automatically move the cursor at the appropriate line.  Or you can manually find the error line number with a query like this: `select * from user_errors where name = 'ISVALIDDATE';`